# How to have a locator map display the study area or IOT with out you setting it yourself

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layouts

I have  included a locator map but i would like to make it dynamic in a way that when the user is mapping changes to a different area to map the locator map should change the location automatically.

Comment: "IOT" is not a term that I have come across - can you [edit] your question to define it, please?

Answer (score 2):

Right-click to get the properties of the data frame for the location map. On the Data Frame tab you have the option to set the Extent to "Other Data Frame". I think this is what you are after. Good Luck.

[image]